# Routing in Rails 3: Map with options?

Tags: routes, ruby-on-rails-3

I can't seem to find documentation on mapping routes with options in rails 3.

As a specific example, I need to translate

```
map.with_options :controller => 'users' do |signup|
    signup.signup '/signup',
      :action => 'landing',
      :conditions => { :method => :get }
    signup.premium '/signup/premium',
      :action => 'new',
      :level => 'premium',
      :conditions => { :method => :get }    
    signup.premium '/signup/premium',
      :action => 'create',
      :level => 'premium',
      :conditions => { :method => :post }
    signup.free '/signup/free',
      :action => 'new',
      :level => 'free',
      :conditions => { :method => :get }    
    signup.free '/signup/free',
      :action => 'create',
      :level => 'free',
      :conditions => { :method => :post }      
  end
```

Into proper syntax for rails3. I'm sure it must be simple that I've overlooked, but any help or links to articles would be wondrous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
scope '/signup' do
    match '/signup' => "users#landing", :as => :signup
    get '/:level' => 'users#new', :as => :signup_new
    post '/:level' => 'users#create', :as => :signup_create
end
```

This is specifically what I was looking for, it was unclear at first (to me) that this is how options would translate.

Comment: I would add that I need to add constraints to these to only allow free and premium as options for the level, but that's relatively trivial.

Answer (score 0):

read http://guides.rails.info/index.html (edge rails docs) to see how you can translate your rails 2.x routes

Comment: Thanks but I'd already read all of this, I was hoping for a specific example.

Answer (score 0):

```
scope '/signup' do
 with_options :controller => :users do |signup|
    signup.match '/signup', :action => :landing
    signup.get '/:level', :action => :new, :as => :signup_new 
      # or just signup.get '/:level/new', :action => :new
    signup.post '/:level', :action => :create, :as => :signup_create
 end
end
```